# Pass data from Flutter Stream to widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, widget

I am trying to work out how to pass data from stream to widget to display out elements

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BrowseTasks extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'feed_screen';
  final String currentUserId;

  BrowseTasks({this.currentUserId});

  @override
  _BrowseTasksState createState() => _BrowseTasksState();
}

class _BrowseTasksState extends State<BrowseTasks> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').snapshots();

  Widget _buildTask(data) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(108, 212, 196, 1),
                  // backgroundImage: _displayProfileImage(),
                  child: Text(
                    'P',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                title: Text(
                    data.title,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                trailing:
                    Text(data.budget, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),

              ),
              Divider(),
              ListTile(
                leading: Text(data.owner),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
              ),

              ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    // textColor: const Color(0xFF6200EE),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Perform some action
                    },
                    child: const Text('ACTION 1'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    // textColor: const Color(0xFF6200EE
                    // ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Perform some action
                    },
                    child: const Text('ACTION 2'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // Image.asset('assets/card-sample-image.jpg'),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Browse task'),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                height: 3.0,
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(4.0)),
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _usersStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print('Has error: ${snapshot.hasError}');
              print('Has data: ${snapshot.hasData}');
              print('Snapshot Data ${snapshot.data.docs}');
              print('Connection State ${snapshot.connectionState}');
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircularProgressIndicator(
                          valueColor:
                              new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                      // Loader Animation Widget
                      Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
                      Text('Finding tasks'),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }

              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final documents = snapshot.data.docs;
                return ListView(
                    children: documents
                        .map(
                          (doc) => _buildTask(doc),
                        )
                        .toList());
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('It\'s Error!');
              }
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Unable to  find any tasks'),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, aren't already doing that? Is there an error somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if you have field name called "name" in task collection

```
class BrowseTasks extends StatefulWidget {
static final String id = 'feed_screen';
final String currentUserId;

BrowseTasks({this.currentUserId});

@override
_BrowseTasksState createState() => _BrowseTasksState();
}

class _BrowseTasksState extends State<BrowseTasks> {
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').get();

Widget _buildTask(data) {
    return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(108, 212, 196, 1),
              // backgroundImage: _displayProfileImage(),
              child: Text(
                'P',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            title: Text(
                data.title,
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
            trailing:
                Text(data.budget, style:         Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),

          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: Text(data.owner),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
          ),

          ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                // textColor: const Color(0xFF6200EE),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Perform some action
                },
                child: const Text('ACTION 1'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                // textColor: const Color(0xFF6200EE
                // ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Perform some action
                },
                child: const Text('ACTION 2'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // Image.asset('assets/card-sample-image.jpg'),
        ],
      ),
    ));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Browse task'),
      bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            height: 3.0,
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(4.0)),
      elevation: 0,
    ),
    body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _usersStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print('Has error: ${snapshot.hasError}');
          print('Has data: ${snapshot.hasData}');
          print('Snapshot Data ${snapshot.data.docs}');
          print('Connection State ${snapshot.connectionState}');
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                  // Loader Animation Widget
                  Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
                  Text('Finding tasks'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           
            return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document){
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String,   dynamic>;
                    ListTile(title:Text(data['name'])

                    ).toList());}
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('It\'s Error!');
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Unable to  find any tasks'),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }));
     }
  }
```

Comment: this got me partway there. I made some changes but this helped me greatly